# How to parse a Dictionary according to its index?

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary and i want to parse the dictionary according to the index of the keys inside dictionary.Actually i want to switch to different dictionaries as per the value of current variable which mean i want to keep accessing the object inside my dictionary according to the index.

```
k = k+1;
NSDictionary * checkBox = [step objectForKey:@"CheckBoxSingle"];
NSDictionary * first = [checkBox objectAtIndex:k];
```

Thanks

Comment: Also note that the order of the elements you put into NSDictionary is not preserved, so "index" is rather meaningless.

Comment: Question does not parse.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop

```
int k;
for (k=0;k<LIMIT;k++) {  //change LIMIT to number of times to loop.
    NSDictionary * checkBox = [step objectForKey:@"CheckBoxSingle"];
    //NSDictionary doesn't respond to objectAtIndex:
    //do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://foobarpig.com/iphone/iterating-through-nsdictionary.html) you have a couple of examples to iterate through an nsdictionary. Using his first example, you can access arbitery values using the array from `[checkBox allKeys];`. Not that you should do it using an NSDictionary because the order of stuff AFAIK can be completley random. You can look into sorting an NSArray though if it will serve your purpose.

Also NSDictionary implements NSFastEnumeration, which means that if you want you can do;

```
for (NSString *currentKey in checkBox)
{
    NSDictionary *current = [checkBox objectForKey:currentKey];
}
```